# What happens when a C++ anonymous object replaces previously assigned object?

Tags: c++, constructor

This question concerns what happens to an object when a variable is assigned to a new object.

```
Date {
    public:
        Date(int day, int month);
        int day;
        int month;
};
```

in main:

```
Date birthday(7,4); //line 1
birthday = Date(5,5); //line 2
```

My understanding is that line 2's RS returns an anonymous object. My question is, what happens to the object that was created with the values 7,4? Is it replaced in memory by the anonymous object?

Comment: The object created with 7, 4 is `birthday`. It continues to exist until it goes out of scope. Line 2 just modifies that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** replace some object with another.

What you *can* do, and what actually happens in your example, is move-assigning from a temporary object to some target-object.

If it was not a temporary object, move-assigning from it would not happen, instead copy-assigning would take place.

Neither changes which object it is, only what value it has.

BTW: Copy-assignment, Move-assignment, copy-construction, move-construction and destruction for your example-class are implicitly defined as member-by-member.

Comment: Technically you can replace an object, using placement new.

Comment: Perilous enough to not be considered, though technically possible, under some circumstances at least.